# Do not return to axios call after call has been made

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to build a registration using axios and run into some issue.
Is it possible in an axios call to submit data to the backend and immediately after refreshing the page to a new one, without returning back to the axios call?

Currently, I have this solution:

```
   axios.post('/traveller-register', this.form.data)
   .then(function(response){
     toastr.success(response.data.status);
     setTimeout(function(){
       window.location = response.data.redirect;
     }, 6000);
   })
```

It shows a success message after returning successfully, then redirects after a certain amount of time, but what I would like to have is when the call returns to send it to a different page directly without returning to axios, is that possible somehow?

I am using laravel as a backend, and axios / vue for frontend.

Comment: Remove the `setTimeout`

Comment: That will work, however, it will block my success message from displaying and I want to show this message on page reload

Comment: Look in to adding some kind of messages to your application state. Pop them from the list on every page and add to them whenever you need to.

Comment: Yes, I used browser session storage and that seems to be working luckily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who run into a similar issue, the solution I found now was to save the needed data into session storage of the browser after respone from axios and display the message on page redirect:

Setting message before reload:

```
axios.post('/register', this.form.data)
 .then(function(response){
   sessionStorage.setItem("flashmessage", response.data.status); // status message
   window.location = response.data.redirect // route for redirection
}
```

Getting message and displaying it on page reload once:

```
<script>
if (sessionStorage.flashmessage) {
  toastr.success(sessionStorage.flashmessage);
  sessionStorage.removeItem('flashmessage');
}
</script>
```

I used the information from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible. You need the `then()` function to exist to trigger the resolution of the Axios call and thus the firing off that HTTP request.

If you dont want a delay just remove the 6 second timeout delay?

Comment: Yes, that would work, however, I am also showing sort of a success message. If I redirect immediately the success message is broken off and the page is reloaded to the new page directly :/ would that mean there is no other way than completely abandoning axios in this case and use html form submit??? 

The success message can be passed along using laravel from the backend, but for that to work it has to send to the new page directly, without going back to the old page first ...

Comment: Yes that works. Your question wasnt asking about the storing of the success message and persisting that to the next page :)

Comment: Sometimes its kinda hard to depict exactly what should be asked so that people understand what exactly is the issue, but I do agree with you that it might have been better to outline this in a sentence :)